# How to create controller api get FormData from client - Odoo16

Tags: javascript, controller, multipartform-data, form-data, odoo-16

This my code but now controller not get value `FromData` from client

1. Controller
   [image]
2. Js
   [image]
3. Html
   [image]
4. fetchApi function
   [image]

Currently, the frontend can send data to the backend in JSON form, but when sending using formdata, the backend does not receive the data.